# Display number of items from array of objects without duplicate

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, duplicates

I'm learning javascript and I have some problems.
I would like to iterate an array of objects but with a few "options":

- don't display duplicate items.
- display the number of items.

expected result :

```
received 1

missed 2

dialed 3
```

I know how to iterate a array of objects and use `.length` to display the quantity of each item but I don't know iterate + display quantity + remove duplicates... Can you help me ?

```
const calls = [
  {
    type: "missed",
    date: "xx-xx-xx"
  },
  {
    type: "received",
    date: "xx-xx-xx"
  },
  {
    type: "dialed",
    date: "xx-xx-xx"
  },
  {
    type: "missed",
    date: "xx-xx-xx"
  },
  {
    type: "dialed",
    date: "xx-xx-xx"
  },
  {
    type: "dialed",
    date: "xx-xx-xx"
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to group items is with reduce (it’s also flexible, so if you add another type it works no problem):

```js
const calls = [{
    type: "missed",
    date: "xx-xx-xx"
  },
  {
    type: "received",
    date: "xx-xx-xx"
  },
  {
    type: "dialed",
    date: "xx-xx-xx"
  },
  {
    type: "missed",
    date: "xx-xx-xx"
  },
  {
    type: "dialed",
    date: "xx-xx-xx"
  },
  {
    type: "dialed",
    date: "xx-xx-xx"
  }
];

const output = calls.reduce((aggObj, item) => {
    if(!aggObj[item.type]){
        aggObj[item.type] = 0
    }
    aggObj[item.type] += 1;
    return aggObj;
}, {});
//output as object:
console.log(output);

//output as array:
const outArr = Object.entries(output);
console.log(outArr);

//output as strings:
outArr.forEach(([k,v]) => console.log(k,v));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const calls = [{
    type: "missed",
    date: "xx-xx-xx"
  },
  {
    type: "received",
    date: "xx-xx-xx"
  },
  {
    type: "dialed",
    date: "xx-xx-xx"
  },
  {
    type: "missed",
    date: "xx-xx-xx"
  },
  {
    type: "dialed",
    date: "xx-xx-xx"
  },
  {
    type: "dialed",
    date: "xx-xx-xx"
  }
];
const types = ["missed", "received", "dialed"];
types.forEach(type => {
  console.log(type + ": " + calls.filter((calls) => calls.type === type).length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps

```js
var newArr = calls.filter((x, index, self) =>
  index === self.findIndex((t) => (
    t.type === x.type && t.date === x.date)));

console.log(newArr);
```